# Special TableView in Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, dictionary

[image]

As you see above, I have a Table View on LeftSide which contains a Some Text.

But when i selected any annotation in map according to that the cell will be Highlighted & it has more text rather than other Cell and also background color is changed.

**How can i achieve this?**

Answer (score 2):

You can approach in following way.
First both table data and annotation pins in Map are filled from an array!!
What you can do, you can define "tag" as array index to particular item.
When a user tap on a annotation, that annotation has a "tag" (or array index) and this "tag" (or array index) also has an item for table data.
On click of annotation tap, you have to reload your table and make that particular tableview cell highlighted.

Comment: But how can i adjust the size of cell when selected & unselected.

Comment: Use - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; delegate method.
Return a float value to change the size of the row

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to customize the `UITableViewCell` for this
2. Add a table view and map view in your view as shown in figure.
3. Load the custom table view cell to tableview
4. Initially give the needed color for all table cells
5. When user selects a cell change it's color
6. Using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method show the corresponding value on map.

Check this link for tutorials:

- [Appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

Comment: Thanks for reply..how can i use different customize `UITableViewCell` & when i select any annotation , according to that cell will be selected.

Comment: @user1673099: when you select the annotation use the 'selectRowAtindexPath` option for selecting the cell

Comment: but hoe can i adjust the size of tableview cell when it is selected.

Comment: @user1673099 reload the table view and use `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method

Answer (score 0):

The basic sample for slide menu in iOS

https://github.com/nverinaud/NVSlideMenuController

Hope this sample code will helps you

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating custom annotation instead of the default one so if it is possible for you to set tag for each annotation view which will be same as tableview cell index. While selecting an annotation create indexpath with that tag and set selectedrow for that indexpath. Hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your customized class of `UITableViewCell`.
2. Understand you have two conditions A. Normal Cell B. Cell after the click.

You'll have to use 3 delegate methods of UITableView to achieve this.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Here you'll have to check for the condition you'll have to check which indexPath.row is selected. and according to that you'll have to change the height of your row.
     return hight;

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     // Again the same thing. You'll have to check the condition and load the appropriate controls with appropriate frames.
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     // This is the important function for you.
     // Here you'll have to set one counter. Which you'll use in the 
     // After that reload the table.
}
```